# rotating along sphere surface while facing target

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, quaternions, spherical-coordinates

I am looking for some help on moving a point (which is a camera) along the surface of a 3D sphere. The point I am moving is my 'camera'(green in my diagram) and it is fixed looking at the target point(the red circle in my image). I have looked up 'arcball camera' but have not found any great resources to explain how to move a point along a surface in 3D. I want to make sure the orientation of the camera maintains its own local transform as well.

Quarternions seem to be the correct approach, but I am not sure, or perhaps do not understand if they solve my problem. I think there must be some other way to use spherical coordinates and vectors?

If it helps, I am doing this in C++ and OpenGL and using the GLM mathematics library. Though if I understand the math a bit more on the rotation, I think I can do the implemenetation.

[image]

Comment: Your question and drawing are confusing. For one, the camera is represented by a triangle but is supposed to be a "point". Is the target point supposed inside the sphere?

Comment: Also, what is the input that determines the camera's trajectory along the sphere? I suspect that you want to interpret an up/down/left/right input as movement along the surface of the sphere, is that correct?

Comment: Is this [answer]
(https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3910421) of interest for you ?

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Ah sorry, the 'green' represents the 'arc' along the curve. It looks a bit like a triangle, but the arc represents a series of points along the spheres surface.

Comment: @Mike And is that arc along the sphere supposed to be the path that the camera takes?

Comment: Yes correct! So there would be a start an a finish defined on the sphere, and the 'camera' would move along that arc. This image might be a bit more clear for what I am trying to achieve: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/gl_trackball01.png

Comment: Try to use vectors - the vector to your target is fixed and the location of the camera changes. Subtract the camera location vector from the target location.

Comment: Right, subtracting the target location from my camera gives me a direction, and I can also compute the distance. How to move in an arc along all 3 axes is the next question? I think I can perhaps rotate around an arc using the cameras 'up' vector, but need some help figuring out if that is the next right step.